# Using java arrays

Tags: java

I have 7 lines of data in a text file (shown below).

```
name: abcd
temp: 623.2
vel: 8

name: xyz
temp: 432
vel: 7.6
```

Using regex, I was able to read this data and I have been able to print it out. Now I need to store this data in some variable. I'm leaning towards storing this data in an array/ matrix. So physically, it would look something like this:

```
  data = [abcd, 623.2, 8 
          xyz, 432, 7.6]
```

So in effect, 1st row contains the first 3 lines, the 2nd row contains lines from 5 to 7. My reason for choosing this type of variable for storage is that in the long run, calling out the data will be simpler - as in:

```
   data[0][0] = abcd
   data[1][1] = 432
```

I can't use the java matrix files from math.nist.gov because I'm not the root user and getting the IT dept to install stuff on my machine is proving to be a MAJOR waste of time. So I want to work with the resources I have - which is Eclipse and a java installation version 1.6.

I want to get this data and store it into a java array variable. What I wanted to know is: is choosing the array variable the right way to proceed? Or should I use a vector variable (altho, in my opinion, using a vector variable will complicate stuff)? or is there some other variable that will **allow me to store data easily and call it out easily**?

Btw, a little more details regarding my java installation - in case it helps in some way:

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0-b09)
OpenJDK 64-bit Server VM (build 1.6.0-b09, mixed mode)

Thank you for your help

Comment: Arrays can only be used for homogeneous data types, you cannot store values of different data type in same array.

Comment: Your question is very basic, so explain your background:  Do you know how to declare a Java array?  Do you understand that strings and numerics are different types?  Do you know what an object is?

Answer (score 9):

It seems to me that

```
name: abcd
temp: 623.2
vel: 8
```

is some sort of object, and you'd do well to store a [list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html) of these e.g. you would define an object

```
public class MyObject {
   private String name;
   private double temp;
   private double vel;

   // etc...
}
```

(perhaps - there may be more appropriate types), and store these in a list:

```
List<MyObject>
```

If you need to index them via their name attribute, then perhaps store a [map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) (e.g.`Map<String, MyObject>`) where the key is the name of the object.

I'm suggesting creating an object for these since it's trivially easy to ask for `obj.getName()` etc. rather than remember or calculate array index offsets. Going forwards, you'll be able to add behaviour to these objects (e.g. you have a `temp` field - with an object you can retrieve that in centigrade/kelvin/fahrenheit etc.). Storing the raw data in arrays doesn't really allow you to leverage the functionality of a OO language.

(note re your installation woes - these classes are native to the Java JRE/JDK and don't require installations. They're fundamental to many programs in Java)

Comment: Arrays should only be used to hold homogenous data that all carries more or less the same meaning, which really doesn't apply here.

Comment: I agree.  This would be the best way to go.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an array, but rather than doing a two dimensional array, create a Data Class that holds the elements and then have an array of those elements.

For example:

```
public class MyData {
  String name;
  float temp;
  int vel;
}
```

then you could define

```
 MyData arr[];
```

You could also use a List() instead of an Array, depending on if you had sorting/searching type criteria.  This approach gives you a lot more flexibility if you ever add an element or if you want to find duplicates or searching.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap this information

```
name: xyz
temp: 432
vel: 7.6
```

in a class of it's own.

And use whichever implementation of a `List<T>` you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can rely on **java Collection framework**.

1. You can use *ArrayList instead of Arrays* if there is a *particular sequence in the data*.
2. Moreover if you want to store data in *key value pairs*, then use *Map*.

Note: If you need sorted values, then use **ArrayList with Comparator or Comparable Interface**.
 If you are using **Map and you need unique and sorted values, then use TreeMap**

Comment: Thanks for that edit, @Brian. Kumar, see that I am not the only one who's bothered by your odd formatting? Again, PLEASE, stop doing that? (Or explain WHY you're doing it? Maybe there's some misunderstanding?)

Comment: Can anyone please point me to the link, where the formatting rules are written, as i have no idea about it. i am here from just past 40 days

Comment: And please does content has lost its value, to the wrapper around it ?? atleast is there anyone who can comment few lines on my answer then on the editing

Comment: The [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) explains that backticks are for code. You're using them everywhere where things are not code. As for the bold: that has not been defined anywhere I guess, but *why* would you want that much emphasis on random words?

Comment: @Kumar - No offense. I use the 'code' formatting (grey background) for code and object names, and bold for (well), stuff I'm really, really emphasising. I'm sure there'll be formatting guidelines on the Meta SO site

Comment: Well thanks for the link..and please see it arjan dear, those are not random words, but the sentence that needs to be paid special attention. But anyhow ....i am glad that i got good tips on formatting from Brian and you Arjan

Answer (score 0):

Provided that all keys in the key-value pair that you are reading are unique, why don't you store items in a `java.util.Map`?

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+): (\\w+)");
try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data.txt"))){

    Map<String, String> items = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    String line = null;
    while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
        while(matcher.find()){
            items.put(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2));
        }
    }

    System.out.println(items);

}catch(IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

The map would then contain: `{name=xyz, temp=432, vel=7}`

And you could easily read a particular element like: `items.get("name")`